# codeigniter only returning year of mysql datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

i am trying to do a simple `SELECT` of some mysql data, using codeigniter.

```
//setup query
$this->db->select('personId, birthday')
    ->from('person')
    ->where('personId', $personId)
    ->limit(1);

    //execute query
    $query = $this->db->get();

    //fetch result
    $result = $query->row_array();

        //found person
        if(!empty($result)){
            echo $result['birthday'];
        }
    }
}
```

the `birthday` field is in mySQL as a `DATE` type. the value in the DB and seen in phpMyAdmin is '1980-05-21', but the value echoed in the above code is simply '1980', just the year.

I tried switching the mysql type to `DATETIME` but that did nothing.

my guess is it has something to do with Codeigniter, and possibly even the '-' character in the result. this problem is driving me crazy! anyone had this problem, and know how to fix it?

Comment: almost embarrassed to admit the answer. i made the type changes to my production db instead of my development db. oops. thanks for all the suggestions though. sometimes just need some input from others to find your stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicate your code and all works fine, may be it's something in your php.ini. Set date.timezone and checks locale settings if you has intl extension.
For test purposes try die() after echo $result... maybe something it's happening after.
I test your code with CodeIgniter 2.1.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your question because I'm not sure about your problem with `date` but it seems that you have an option to change the field because you already changed it once (as mentioned in your question) so, in my opnion, using a `timestamp` is better than `date/datetime` and here is a [nice answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126208/datetime-vs-timestamp-in-mysql-and-php-in-practice) about it, so, I think if you change the type to `timestamp` it may solve the problem and it's easy to handle any kind of manipulation on a `timestamp`, also, `CodeIgniter` has a [Date Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html) to handle date it easily but it's only an option, you may use `PHP`'s built-in functions as well.

This is only an opinion, I prefer `timestamp` over `date/datetime`, at least, I don't need to swap the order between `yyyy-mm-dd` and `dd-mm-yyyy`, instead I can just create it using something like `date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);` from the `timestamp`.

Comment: i've actually read that article already, and much more on best uses for timestamp vs. datetime. i'm actually updating from a really old practice of storing dates as BIGINTs, so either is an improvement for me. i tend to use timestamp for more metadata, and datetime otherwise. i'm sticking with `date` for this one (unless i can't find a solution), but thanks for the suggestion. also PHP's new DateTime class is great FYI